# Is there a way to show the exact place where two files differ using FC command? or any other good way to compare 2 files in windows?

Tags: windows, file-comparison

I'm comparing two files with the command:

```
  FC /W file1.txt file2.txt > log.txt
```

And I'm getting 4000 lines of differences...

But when it shows the difference, it just paste 3~5 lines from each file and I sorta have to compare them myself to find the place where the difference occured.

Is there a way to make it easier to see where the difference is? Maybe something like adding a flag like "HERE" in one of them where it first differ from the other?

Comment: Is the usage of `fc` command a necessity for you? There are many more options, both command-line and GUI for any modern OS available

Comment: I could use other tool.. I'm just not aware of other ways to compare files in windows, what would you suggest?

Comment: Probably something like googling for "compare text files"? There are too many options for you to choose from so you'd have to do some searching

Comment: hum, thanks for the hint... try a couple programs here and see if they have a better diff display

Comment: I personally like the diff version that comes with Perforce (and is a stand-alone application that you can use without the P4 itself). Other diff-ers I've used and liked are a built-in that comes with my favorite light-weight text editor `Notepad++`

Comment: I use notepad++ but didn't know it had a diff embedded... I found a online diff tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [online diff](http://www.diffnow.com/) very useful and simple to use... very good error displaying showing too